# Quicksort array is not printing out correctly? (java)

Tags: java, arrays, quicksort

I'm currently working on a university assignment which involves implementing sorting algorithms. I believe I have correctly implemented the quicksort algorithm, however in the test class the method just prints out the array being read in without sorting it. Below is the code from the test class, and the code for the actual quicksort(which is in a seperate class called 'sort'). 
Has anyone got any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Sort {

/** Array of integers to sort **/
private int[] A;

/** Size of the array **/
private int size;

/** Number of elements actually used in array **/
private int usedSize;

/** Global variables for counting sort comparisons **/
public int compIS;
/** Global comparison count for Insertion Sort **/
public int compQS;
/** Global comparison count for Quicksort **/
public int compNewS;

/** Global comparison count for new sort **/

/*****************/
/** Constructor **/
/*****************/
Sort(int max) {
    /** Initialiase global sort count variables **/
    compIS = 0;
    compQS = 0;
    compNewS = 0;

    /** Initialise size variables **/
    usedSize = 0;
    size = max;

    /** Create Array of Integers **/
    A = new int[size];
}

public int getRightElement() {
    return usedSize - 1;
}

public int getLeftElement() {
    return A[0];
}

/*********************************************/
/*** Read a file of integers into an array ***/
/*********************************************/
public void readIn(String file) {
    try {
        /** Initialise loop variable **/
        usedSize = 0;

        /** Set up file for reading **/
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(reader);

        /** Loop round reading in data while array not full **/
        while (in.hasNextInt() && (usedSize < size)) {
            A[usedSize] = in.nextInt();
            usedSize++;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error processing file " + file);
    }
}

/**********************/
/*** Display array ***/
/**********************/
public void display(int line, String header) {
    /*** Integer Formatter - three digits ***/
    NumberFormat FI = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    FI.setMinimumIntegerDigits(3);

    /** Print header string **/
    System.out.print("\n" + header);

    /** Display array data **/
    for (int i = 0; i < usedSize; i++) {
        /** Check if new line is needed **/
        if (i % line == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }

        /**
         * Display an ar ray element
         **/
        System.out.print(FI.format(A[i]) + " ");
    }
}
public void quick(int L, int R) {
    /* ensure there is more than one element in array */
    if (R > L) {
        /* split array in two */
        int pLoc = partition(L, R);
        /* sort left half */
        quick(L, pLoc - 1);
        /* sort right half */
        quick(pLoc + 1, R);
    }

    System.out.println("\n\nAfter  QuickSort: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < usedSize; i++) {
        System.out.println(A[i] + " ");
    }
}

/* partitions array for quicksort */
public int partition(int L, int R) {
    /* Select pivot */
    int pivot = A[R];
    /* initialise scanning pointers */

    int pR = R;
    int pL = L;
    /* repeat until pointers cross */
    while (pL < pR) {
        compQS++;
        /* move left pointer */
        while (A[pL] < pivot) {
            pL++;
        }
        /* move right pointer */
        while ((A[pR] >= pivot) && (pR > L)) {
            pR--;
            //compQS++;
        }
        /* swap elements */
        //compQS++;
        if (pL < pR) {
            swap(pL, pR);
             L++;
             R--;
        }
    }


    /* put pivot in correct position */
    swap(pL, R);
    /* return pivot position */
    return pL;

}

/* swaps elements in quicksort */
public void swap(int i, int j) {
    int temp = A[i];
    A[i] = A[j];
    A[j] = temp;
}


    public class TestSort
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Sort sortTest = new Sort(100);



    /** Read in test data into array **/
    sortTest.readIn("test1.txt");

    /** Display array **/
    sortTest.display(10,"Input Array 1");
    /*apply insertion sort to array*/
    //sortTest.insertion(); 

    //sortTest.readIn("test1.txt");
    sortTest.quick(sortTest.getLeftElement(), sortTest.getRightElement());
    sortTest.newSort();

    /** Display comparison counters **/
    System.out.println("Quicksort comparison counter: " + sortTest.compQS);
    System.out.println("\n\nInsertion sort comparison counter: " + sortTest.compIS);


}
```

Comment: Can you paste everything? I would recommend you to post this into code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Provide runnable code please.

Comment: @Admit. There is a problem with this code, so SO is the right place. The phrasing of the question is incomplete though.

Comment: @Admit I've updated the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your problems is that `getLeftElement()` is returning the value at position `0` within your array instead of just returning `0`. In situations in which the value of the first element in the array is greater than the size of the array, no sorting will be done.

Also, I believe that your implementation of the method `quick` is incorrect. Within the method you recursively invoke `quick(L, pLoc - 1)`
and `quick(pLoc + 1, R)`. By invoking in this manner, you do not traverse all indices of the array in your array. (Ex if `L` is `0`, `R` is `10`, and `pLoc` is `5`, then you do not involve the index 5 in the sorting of your array.)